# javascript keeping a var within inner functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

I am making a website based dashboard. one of the functionalities is showing the locations of all customers. when i'm placing these on the map i can't seem to get the pop-up right.

```
function getCoordinates(locationList) {
            for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
                if (locationList[i].city != null) {
                    $http.get('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + locationList[i].city + '.json?access_token=' + access_token)
                        .success(
                            function (data) {
                                var marker = L.marker([data.features[0].center[1], data.features[0].center[0]]).addTo(mymap);
                                marker.bindPopup(locationList[i].customerName);
                            }
                        );
                }
            }
        }
```

When I use this code the pop-up will only contain the last customer's name in every pop-up.does someone know how to make sure that the attributes of the correct user are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a closure problem, to fix it you have to move your $http call to a new function like this.

```
function httpCall(locationList,i){
         $http.get('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + locationList[i].city + '.json?access_token=' + access_token)
                        .success(
                            function (data) {
                                var marker = L.marker([data.features[0].center[1], data.features[0].center[0]]).addTo(mymap);
                                marker.bindPopup(locationList[i].customerName);
                            }
        );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `for` loop `i` is always `locationList.length - 1`. Try to add IIFE with local `i`. For example you can solve the problem with replacing `for` loop with `locationList.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope problem. Your `i` is updated and later, when you will click on the popup, it will read the last value of `i`.

You should put your conditional in the `for` a function which take in parameter the `i` :

```
function getCoordinates(locationList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
    conditionalGet(i);
  }
  function conditionalGet(i) {
    if (locationList[i].city != null) {
      $http.get('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + locationList[i].city + '.json?access_token=' + access_token)
        .success(function (data) {
          var marker = L.marker([data.features[0].center[1], data.features[0].center[0]]).addTo(mymap);
          marker.bindPopup(locationList[i].customerName);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **Infamous Loop Problem**. Since you are just defining the function and not actually executing it when the for loop ends all the functions will have the same values for index `i`.

**Solution:** Is to assign the value to a variable and use this variable inside you success callback.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
   if (locationList[i].city != null) {    
   var currLocation = locationList[i]; // assign the data to a variable 
   $http.get('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + locationList[i].city + '.json?access_token=' + access_token)
   .success(
            function (data) {
              var marker = L.marker([data.features[0].center[1], data.features[0].center[0]]).addTo(mymap);
              marker.bindPopup(currLocation.customerName); // use the variable instead of the indexed lookup
             }
           );
   }
 }
```

Let me know if this helps.